# Storing and retrieving data from session in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.6 and my php is 7.3. I am trying to store data in session. I tried

```
use Session;
session()->put( 'item_data', [1,2,3]);
dd(Session::get( 'item_data' ));
```

it shows value properly but problem is if I tried another request then it's showing null. That's mean it's working instantly storing in session. After that showing null

Comment: try : `Session::put('key', 'value')`; or `session(['key' => 'value'])`

Comment: Same problem ........

Comment: The session only works after the `StartSession` middleware has ran. Can you check if your route runs this middleware (i.e. it's not an `api` route)